To show the post data from the front end application in the backend php
I am new to PHP, I would like to develop a simple API in php that is to print out the login name and password in the page of the API php:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");


$eData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dData = json_decode($eData, true);

$staff = $dData['staff'];
$pass = $dData['pass'];

echo json_encode($staff);
echo json_encode($pass);

However, error messages are shown in the browser:

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

I have tried to run the program by inputting some text (e.g. I enter "Peter" in the field of login Name, and I enter "12345" in the field of password, I can see both the login name and password are found in the response of the network.  Therefore, it seems that the API connection works, but why I can’t print out the code in the php?  And how I can do that?
Below is my react program for your reference:
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Login() {

const [loginName, setLoginName] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [error, setError] = useState('');

        const handleInputChange = (e, type) => {
           switch(type){
           case "staff":
               setError("");
               setLoginName(e.target.value);
               if(e.target.value === ""){
                setError("Staff name has left blank");
                }
               break;
           case "pass":
               setError("");
               setPassword(e.target.value);
               if(e.target.value === ""){
                setError("Password has left blank");
               }
             break;
           default:
       }
     }

    var url_LOGIN = "localhost3000/login.php";

    var Data = {
          staff: loginName,
          pass: password
     };

    const loginSubmit = async(e)=>{
         e.preventDefault();

         if (loginName !== "" && password !== "") {
        
          const responseData=await axios.post(url_LOGIN, Data);

            console.log(responseData);
            
        }
    }
    


    return (

    <div style={{display: 'flex',
         justifyContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         flexDirection: 'column',
         height: '100vh'}}>
    <form>

    <div>
    <div style={{display: 'flex', fontSize: '30px'}}>
                <label  style={{ width: '250px' }}>Login Name: 
  </label>
                <input  style={{ width: '250px', marginLeft: 
 '-50px'}} type = "text"  value = {loginName}  onChange= 
{(e)=>handleInputChange(e, "staff")}/>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div style={{display: 'flex', fontSize: '30px'}}>
                <label  style={{ width: '250px' }}>Password:</label>
                <input  style={{ width: '250px', marginLeft: 
  '-50px'}} type = "password"  value = {password} onChange= 
   {(e)=>handleInputChange(e, "pass")} id="password" min="1" max = 
"6"/>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div style={{display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                fontSize: '30px'}}>

                <input type="submit" value = "Submit" style= 
   {{fontSize: '30px'}} onClick ={loginSubmit} />
    </div>

    </div>

    </form>

    

  </div>
  )
}

Front End Login

Front End Console


Can you add how you send your data ?

Hi, i use axio post method, send data in object form: var Data = {
staff: loginName,
pass: password
};

Please [edit] your question with a [mre] of the issue including precisely how the data is sent. Then we can help you properly.  Thanks

Hi, I have just edited my question to provide more detail information, but i am not familiar how to add pictures here, please see is there anything still unclear, thanks.

Hello, so do you want to print the username and password on the frontpage? I'm not sure what you want exactly.

No., I want to print the username and password in the page of the php, not in the front page.  I use the command "echo json_encode($staff);", i expect i can get the value of the username in the php, however the outcome is this error message "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" shows in the browser, this confuse me.

Trying to access array offset on value of type null...where and when does it show this? The only output we can see is your console.log(responseData); which seems to show that it returned the data successfully from the PHP script. So which "page of the PHP" do you want to show this data on, and how did you try to do that? Which line of code produces the "Trying to access..." error? It's not clear, just from your description. If we have clearer details we can help you more easily. If you provide vague information it's almost impossible - remember we can't see your screen or read your mind!

Are you saying that you're trying to access the PHP script separately, in your browser, without using Axios code to do it? If so then that would produce a GET request, and there would be no posted data in that request, so self-evidently it would not return any data in that situation. You have to send some valid JSON in the POST data in order for your code to have anything to echo! If you want to test your API independently, without using axios/react, then you should use a tool like PostMan to build your HTTP request - you can send any data you want, e.g. JSON etc, with such a tool.

Actually, what i want is very simple, there is an API link, the one axio post to, when i type the API link in the url and enter, the password and usename can be shown in the browser.  You can see in our php file, i have applied the code "echo json_encode($staff); echo json_encode($pass)", i expected they are showing in the browser, not in the Front End console (but at the end it is shown in there)...

when i type the API link in the url and enter, the password and usename can be shown in the browser...this is not possible - and I've already explained why. How do you expect can it show the username password, when you did not send a username and password in the request? Your axios request sends the username and password data in its request, so it can be echoed back by PHP. If you just type the API URL in the browser that does not send any data to PHP, so there is nothing to echo. Your PHP script only echoes back what it was sent. If nothing is sent then nothing is echoed.

Also... why do you want to be able to do that? It doesn't make any sense. An API is designed to be accessed behind the scenes, by requests such as axios requests, or from an app etc. It's not designed for access directly in the browser - that's what your React code is for!

Sorry, i should make it more accurate.  All i want to achieve is:
Once i click on the submit button in the front end, in my backend browser i can see the password and username.  As you can see in my provided image, the password and username is delivered as a response from the backend to the frontend, therefore it is proved that the connection really there and successfully.  The one confused me is why they (username and password) cannot be shown in the backend php browser, since there are already code statement "echo json_encode($staff);" in the php, why it shows the error message instead.

in my backend browser...what does that even mean? What is a "backend browser"? Browsers are front-end only, they do not run on the server. The webserver, which is running the PHP script, is the "back end". Your browser acts as the client, or "front-end", sending a request to the server, which then executes the PHP script, and returns whatever it outputs.

Anyway you seem to be suffering from a misunderstanding of some sort. Let me try one more time to explain it: When you send a request to your PHP script via AXIOS, PHP is reading the the username and password you wrote in your form and sent in your AXIOS request. It then takes that information and echoes it back, as your code asks it to do. Your JavaScript code then puts that response into the console, so you can see it in the browser. If you chose to, you could write JS code to put it somewhere on the web page instead, but you haven't done that.

BUT...when you type the API link as a URL in your browser, and visit it directly, this sends another, different request to the PHP script. The PHP script starts again, from the beginning. It does not remember anything about any data you may have sent to it before (e.g. from your axios request). Instead it tries to read the input data again (using the file_get_contents("php://input") code). But this time, there is no input data, because the browser did not send any - in this case it simply sends a GET request with no data in it....

.... Therefore, this means that, this time, $eData in PHP will be empty. In turn this means $dData will be null, because there was nothing for json_decode to decode. And that then means you cannot write $staff = $dData['staff']; because $dData isn't an array - which is why you get an error about "trying to access an array offset on null".

Thanks.  And yes, you might be right, when I type the API link as a URL in your browser, and visit it directly, this sends another, different request to the PHP script.  But that's my question, how can i make the password and username to be appeared in the page of php?  I believe it is possible to do so, since we have sent back to user name and password to the front end, we can make them to be appeared in the php page.

how can i make the password and username to be appeared in the page of php...well, you'd have to first store the data when it's sent from axios to PHP - e.g. in a file or a database, or maybe just in the Session (which is temporary of course). And then you'd have to have a script which can retrieve that data and display it, when it receives another request. But I still don't know why you'd want to do that, when you're writing an API. As I said before, APIs generally don't have a human-facing interface.

since we have sent back to user name and password to the front end, we can make them to be appeared in the php page... do you really mean that you want to display it in the React app? Well, to do that you'd simply replace the console.log(responseData); with some JavaScript which will insert the data into the right place in the existing page. That would make more sense as a use case.

No, I don't want them to be appeared in React app, i believe they can be shown in the backend.  For example, if I add a code "echo "Hello"; at the end of the above php program, we can see the word "Hello" is appeared in the php page, that's why i believe there should be a way to print the username and password in the php page too, since we can send them back to the front end, we of course can print them in the php page

You are printing them in PHP already. PHP is echoing them, when they are available to echo. You see that in the browser's console because that's where the printed output from your PHP script is returned to, in the case of the axios request. Everything in your code is working properly. If you want to see the result, that's where you can see it.  What you can't do, is see the result of your axios request in a different HTTP request - which is what you're asking for. The only way around that is, as I said, to store the submitted data on the server first, for later retrieval and display.

This is completely different from your simplistic echo "hello"; example - that's just static, hard-coded data...so of course if you write that then PHP will show that same output every time you run the script, no matter where you run it from. But that's because it doesn't rely on any input data in order to do that. Your real code relies entirely on the input data it's given, in order to echo something back. If there's no input data, it can't echo it back - surely this is self-evident??

P.S. in the php page...there is no such thing as a "php page". PHP runs on the server, not in the browser. No matter what you use to execute your PHP script (whether that's a browser, a JS script, Postman, an Android app, a smart fridge, or whatever), the server simply receives a HTTP request, processes it, and outputs some content. If the request happened to come from a browser, the browser will receive that output from PHP and try to display it as a web page. PHP itself knows nothing about pages, or browsers, or anything like that from the client-side.

I think this is where you are still getting confused, because you seem to believe that calling the PHP script directly from your browser can somehow offer a window into what that script will do when it's called from the axios code...but it doesn't. The two things are entirely separate - your PHP runs independently each time it's requested, and (unless you explicitly write code which allows it to, for example, retrieve data from a stored location) it operates entirely and only on the data it's given in that specific request.

Yes, you are right, to store the data (username and password in this case) and display it, this should be able to be done in php, right?  What is the codes in order to do that...

You can store it in the Session, just for temporary storage (and that's restricted only to the current user and browser session, it will not show up if you run the PHP script from anywhere else). There are plenty of tutorials online showing you how to use Sessions in PHP. If you want to get more complex, you could store it in a file or database - again, there are tutorials, books, whole courses on these subjects, but you can find plenty of introductory examples all over the place. I don't need to repeat them here.

N.B. Of course I'm sure this is just for testing / demo purposes? Because in real life you would never store the details of someone's login attempt in your application, let alone re-display the username and password they entered back onto the screen anywhere...that would be an enormous security problem. But if you just want to practice for how you'd store and retrieve user-submitted form data in general then you can practice using any data you want.
